# How to include headers in php mail?

Tags: php, email

I am trying to send a small email from a contact form whenever a user clicks on send button. What I am stuck with is the from option in the header. I am not sure how to include the 'From' email id in the mail/ how to include the sender email. Here is my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="POST">  

<table id ="contact_us" cellpadding="5px">

 <tr>
 <td>Name : </td>
 <td><input style="border-radius: 5px; width: 200px; height: 20px;" type="text" id="name" name="name" required/></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
 <td>Email : </td>
<td><input style="border-radius: 5px; width: 200px; height: 20px;" type="email" id="email" name="email" required/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Comments : </td>
<td><textarea style="border-radius: 5px;" cols = "40" rows="5" id="query" name="query" required></textarea></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><input style="border-radius: 5px; width: 80px; height:25px;" type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Send"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form> 



 <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit'] == 'Send') {
       $mailerName = $_POST['name'];
       $emailer = $_POST['email'];
       $comments = $_POST['query'];


       function sendEmail(){
       $to = "email@domain.com";
       $subject = "emailQuery";
       $message = $comments;
       $headers = 'From: '.$mailerName;.'' . "\r\n" .'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

      $headers = 'From: '.$mailerName;

      mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
                }
      sendEmail();

      echo '
            <div id="emailSent_message" style="border-radius: 2px; border-top: 2px solid gray; padding: 20px;">
            Your email is sent to us and will be responded to as soon as possible. Thankyou for your message!!
            </div>
            ';
            }

  ?>
```

Comment: What do you need to understand there? There's already a From: address. Or is this about the syntax error or the undefined variables (outer scope)?

Comment: the From $mailerName is not working here

Comment: $message = $comments; does not contain any message when I inout some text in the box, the mail is sent without any body. If I hard-code some text there, it goes in the mail fine